# How to make my query columns take up the full page

Tags: php, html, css, multiple-columns, space

Right now I run a query, and it returns the right information. I was just wondering if there was a way to have my columns take up the whole page. Right now they are sort of centered in the middle so there is a large amount of space on the sides. I was wondering if you could expand the columns.

Here is my code.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<p><br><br></p>

<select name="weekNo">
<option value="1">week 1</option>
<option value="2">week 2</option>
<option value="3">week 3</option>
<option value="4">week 4</option>
<option value="5">week 5</option>
<option value="6">week 6</option>
<option value="7">week 7</option>
<option value="8">week 8</option>
<option value="9">week 9</option>
<option value="10">week 10</option>
<option value="11">week 11</option>
<option value="12">week 12</option>
<option value="13">week 13</option>
<option value="14">week 14</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Games" />
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<?php


    session_start();
    $conn = pg_connect(); or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //submit button pressed
    {
    $query=NULL; //prevent compile error

    $weekNum = $_POST['weekNo'];

    $query = "SELECT a.game_no AS \"Game Number\", a.home AS \"Home Team\",
              homeTeam.wins AS \"Home Wins\", homeTeam.losses AS \"Home Losses\",
            a.away AS \"Away Team\", awayTeam.wins AS \"Away Wins\",
            awayTeam.losses AS \"Away Losses\", a.spread AS \"Spread\"
            FROM weekly_stats AS a
            INNER JOIN team AS homeTeam ON a.home = homeTeam.name
            INNER JOIN team AS awayTeam ON a.away = awayTeam.name
            WHERE a.week_no = $weekNum";

    $result = pg_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' .pg_last_error());



            // Printing results in HTML
            echo "<br>There are " . pg_num_rows($result) . " games for this week.\n<p></p>\n";
            echo "<table border=1>\n\t<tr>\n";

            for($i=0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++)
            {
                    echo "\t\t<th>" . pg_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>\n";
            }
            echo "\t\t<th>Picks</th>\n";

            echo "\t</tr>\n";
            $row=0;
$teammnames = array(
 "home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away");
$flag = 0;

while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    $teamnames[$flag] = $line["Home Team"];
    $flag++;
    $teamnames[$flag] = $line["Away Team"];
    $flag++;

    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row]\" value=\"home\">Home
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row]\" value=\"away\">Away</td>";


    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    $row++;
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
    echo"<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit2\" value=\"submit2\"></td>";
    echo "</form>";

        if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
            $flag = 0;
            $row = 0;

            for($row=0;$row<pg_num_rows($result);$row++){

                    if($_POST['picks[$row]'] = "home")
                    {
                    $pick = $teamnames[$flag];
                    $flag+=2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $flag++;
                    $pick = $teamnames[$flag];
                    $flag++;
                    }

            pg_prepare($conn, "myquery", 'INSERT INTO $1.user_picks VALUES ($2,$3,$4,$5)');
            pg_execute($conn, "myquery", array($_SESSION['league'],$_SESSION['username'],$weekNum, $row, $pick));
    }
    }

// Free result set
pg_free_result($result);
}

// Closing connection
pg_close($conn);

?>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please indent the code properly? It makes it a lot easier to read it for us. Which in turn increases the chances for you to get help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<p><br><br></p>

<select name="weekNo">
<option value="1">week 1</option>
<option value="2">week 2</option>
<option value="3">week 3</option>
<option value="4">week 4</option>
<option value="5">week 5</option>
<option value="6">week 6</option>
<option value="7">week 7</option>
<option value="8">week 8</option>
<option value="9">week 9</option>
<option value="10">week 10</option>
<option value="11">week 11</option>
<option value="12">week 12</option>
<option value="13">week 13</option>
<option value="14">week 14</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Games" />
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<?php


    session_start();
    $conn = pg_connect(); or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //submit button pressed
    {
    $query=NULL; //prevent compile error

    $weekNum = $_POST['weekNo'];

    $query = "SELECT a.game_no AS \"Game Number\", a.home AS \"Home Team\",
              homeTeam.wins AS \"Home Wins\", homeTeam.losses AS \"Home Losses\",
            a.away AS \"Away Team\", awayTeam.wins AS \"Away Wins\",
            awayTeam.losses AS \"Away Losses\", a.spread AS \"Spread\"
            FROM weekly_stats AS a
            INNER JOIN team AS homeTeam ON a.home = homeTeam.name
            INNER JOIN team AS awayTeam ON a.away = awayTeam.name
            WHERE a.week_no = $weekNum";

    $result = pg_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' .pg_last_error());



            // Printing results in HTML
            echo "<br>There are " . pg_num_rows($result) . " games for this week.\n<p></p>\n";
            echo "<table width='100%' border=1>\n\t<tr>\n";

            for($i=0; $i<pg_num_fields($result); $i++)
            {
                    echo "\t\t<th>" . pg_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>\n";
            }
            echo "\t\t<th>Picks</th>\n";

            echo "\t</tr>\n";
            $row=0;
$teammnames = array(
 "home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away",
"home", "away");
$flag = 0;

while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    $teamnames[$flag] = $line["Home Team"];
    $flag++;
    $teamnames[$flag] = $line["Away Team"];
    $flag++;

    foreach ($line as $col_value)
    {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }

    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row]\" value=\"home\">Home
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"picks[$row]\" value=\"away\">Away</td>";


    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    $row++;
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
    echo"<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit2\" value=\"submit2\"></td>";
    echo "</form>";

        if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
            $flag = 0;
            $row = 0;

            for($row=0;$row<pg_num_rows($result);$row++){

                    if($_POST['picks[$row]'] = "home")
                    {
                    $pick = $teamnames[$flag];
                    $flag+=2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $flag++;
                    $pick = $teamnames[$flag];
                    $flag++;
                    }

            pg_prepare($conn, "myquery", 'INSERT INTO $1.user_picks VALUES ($2,$3,$4,$5)');
            pg_execute($conn, "myquery", array($_SESSION['league'],$_SESSION['username'],$weekNum, $row, $pick));
    }
    }

// Free result set
pg_free_result($result);
}

// Closing connection
pg_close($conn);

?>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you just change that width to 100%? because it didnt work if thats what you changed

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of your table to 100% to get it appear at full browser width. Columns with no width will be autosized then.

Comment: Make sure you did it with css (or the inline style attribute) and that columns or cells have no width. Maybe you can post a screenshot of what you het and what you want?

Comment: I can't post screenshots unforutnetly. Right now if you split up a webpage into thirds, my answer only fills out the middle column. Ive tried changing the width of my table to 100%, but it didnt change anything. If I make it up to 300% then it fills up the middle column and the right column but I still have a huge blank space on the left side.

Comment: Then you have it inside other elements that cause this table to stay in the middle, I guess. If so, take the table out and place it somewhere it can use the full body width